# How can i Resize Triangle shape using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pascals-triangle

i want to resize triangle using jQuery.I know about jQuery resizable function
but in triangle shape how can i resize it.
Here is code for triangle i want to resize it using mouse

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could simply use a `<input type="range"/>` slider to update the value of the property that is driving the triangle. In your case, this is `border-width`.

```js
$(function() {

  var triangle = $('.triangle');
  var slider = $('#triangle-control');

  slider.on('change', function(e) {

    triangle.css({
      'border-width': this.value + 'px'
    })

  })


});
```

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
  transition: border-width 500ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   
    
    <input id="triangle-control" type="range" min="20" max="100"/>
    
     <div class="triangle"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```